# Howto Use Selenium and Selenium IDE with sites using SAML

Tags: authentication, curl, saml

I need to log into site: 
play.pl 
my mobile provider and fetch some data.

They use SAML. I'm unable to do this using CURL or Selenium. Any ideas what shoud i do/check?

Comment: Do you really need to integrate with the underlaying SAML, if its just  your standard username/password on the login page, you kan just input the credentials using selenium. Or am I not seeing the problem right? is it a awebservice your accessing?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, neither cURL or Selenium has an inbuilt SAML stack.

So you would either have to add a "plug-in" using something like [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) or send a "hard-coded" SAML message.

The problem with the latter is that SAML is very strict re. the time elapsed between send / receive so the time in the message would have to reflect current time.